# Can't execute GET request from Win8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, http-get

I tried to do `GET` request, and i have an `InnerExeption`:

**{"Unable to connect to the remote server"}**, **{"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions myServerAddress:port"}** 
 
 this is my code :

```
        string url = "url_to_my_server";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse response =  request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
```

How can I do `GET` request in win8 app?

For example of `GET` request, I use this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx). I also associate my app with winstoreapp for getting Identity Name and Publisher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use internet connection in your application, you need (a) set the required capability [Internet (Client)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#internet_and_public_networks), (b) use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class, which is new and much easy way to send requests. You will find the set of [GetAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync.aspx) methods, which allow you to send GET request.

Comment: Thanks. I find solution. I checked Private Network(Client & Server), Internet(Client), Internet(Client & Server)

Answer (score 0):

```
resourceUri="url_to_my_server";
HttpClient httpClient=new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri);
```